# How to answer whatsapp calls by pressing the home button?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, accessibility, home-button

Its just for accessibility, as android supports answering phone calls using home button, I want to do this with whatsapp calls too.

Comment: The phone doesn't count WhatsApp calls as a regular phone call. Therefore, it won't work unless you get Tasker or something similar, to use the home button to answer calls

Comment: yes, there is an app that could do it, Automate by llama labs, maybe someone will do it.